# Take a portion of an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, chars

So I have a string of chars which I want to cycle through in a for loop. When I reach a certain char that passes a boolean check, I want to take every item in the list after that point and cut off from there. Like below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < charList.length; i++)
{   if (charList[i] == "a")
    {
        //put every char in charList between i and the end into a new variable
    }
}
```

What ways are there to do this? Which ones are recommended?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?  indexOf could work on a substring, which might be better.  Not sure about Big-Oh performance.

Comment: Look for the `copyOfRange` method:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: The for and if checks are fine. It's the commented part that I don't know how to do.

Comment: Your `if` should be comparing to `'a'` not `"a"` (`char` versus `String`).

Answer (score 3):

The Arrays collection has a [copyOfRange()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28char%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29)  method

```
for (int i = 0; i < charList.length; i++)
{   if (charList[i] == 'a')
    {
        char[] newCharList = Arrays.copyOfRange(charList,i,charList.length);//put every char in charList between i and the end into a new variable
        //do stuff
        break;
    }
}
```

If you need to access the new array outside the for loop, make sure to declare it before entering, i.e.

```
char[] newCharList;
for(...
```

Comment: I think the homework is to create a method that accomplish this.

Comment: shouldn't you exit the loop also?

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you! @Luiggi Mendoza, this isn't homework; I just tried doing a programming challenge and got caught by the syntax. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @SamOfloinn then please specify it's not homework. Also, the variable should be declared outside to be used outsite the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

In your `if`, create a new `char[]` and then place the characters into it.

```
char[] substr = new char[charList.length-i];
for (int j = 0; j < charList.length-i; j++) {
    substr[j] = charList[i+j];
}
break; // out of the loop over i
```

I wrote `break` but you will probably be `return`ing it, or you would declare `substr` outside of this scope. The code I wrote is just to give you the idea.

I made a simple [ideone](http://ideone.com/TXsLMI) for this so you can see it working.

Comment: I think you need to specify this code goes inside the `if` posted by OP.

Answer (score 0):

Use the  copyOfRange() method:

```
char[] charListCopy = Arrays.copyOfRange(charList, i, charList.size());
```